# How to show sticky and z-index section from the top part in Tailwind CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, sticky

I want to implement a scroll effect with a stick and z-index combination. (I am using Tailwind)

The current code behaves similar effect, but the second section does not keep the bottom (does not start from the top element)

What I want to achieve is this - once you scroll the first section top of the screen, next section starts moving from the top element (In this case "Design collaboration shouldn't be extra work" text title)

[image]

Here is a snippet of my code how I construct it.

```
            <div className="bg-blue rounded-b-3xl">
                <div className="sticky bottom-0 z-10">
                    <FirstSection />
                </div>
                <div className="sticky bottom-0 z-[9]">
                    <SecondSection />
                </div>
            </div>
```

The first and second section are completely covered so when I finish scroll the first section, the screen is already in the middle element of the second section (so I can't even see the first element of the second section).

What is the simplest way to achieve this in Tailwind?